# Succesive br Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
function formatResults(){

    $("#answersToSearch").empty();
    var i=0;
    for(;i<answers[1].length;i++){

      var title=document.createTextNode(answers[1][i]);
      var desc=document.createTextNode(answers[2][i]);
      var newLine=document.createElement("br");

      document.getElementById("answersToSearch").appendChild(title);
      document.getElementById("answersToSearch").appendChild(newLine);

      var newLine=document.createElement("br");
      document.getElementById("answersToSearch").appendChild(newLine);

      document.getElementById("answersToSearch").appendChild(desc);
      var newLine=document.createElement("br");
      document.getElementById("answersToSearch").appendChild(newLine);
      var newLine=document.createElement("br");
      document.getElementById("answersToSearch").appendChild(newLine);


    }  

}
```

Initially, I tried using the same variable 'newLine' representing a new line for carriage returns. But it works only once. Then i tried declaring it each time i used a carriage return and it worked. So my question is - Why do i have to declare a new 'br' element each time to add a carriage return. Or is there something that I have done wrong???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. **If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position**

*(Emphasis added)* [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

`appendChild()` does not clone the node. You could clone the node yourself:

```
appendChild(newLine.cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: is there any difference between using it the way i have done it and using cloneNode??

Comment: I am not sure how to answer you without just repeating the answer to the original question. Which part is unclear and needs more info?

Comment: `cloneNode` is almost certainly better for most situations, because if your *intent* is to repeat the node exactly, then you would only want to set it up & declare it once, especially if it was more complicated than a `<br>` tag and it had a lot of properties and settings you also wanted to repeat.